# How to replace a character in NSString without inserting a space?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Let's assume I have the string

```
NSString* myString  = @"Hello,";
```

How can I remove the comma without leaving a space? I have tried:

```
NSString* newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

and

```
NSString* newString = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
```

But both are leaving spaces.

Comment: No they're not, something else is occurring.

Comment: How are you verifying that there is a space?  Can you show that code? I bet the problem is there.

Comment: I am tokenizing my strings. I separated hello and the , as two separate tokens. When building a string out of the tokens, there was a space between Hello and ,

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I just ran the following as a test

```
NSString * myString = @"Hello,";

NSString * newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@xx",newString);
```

And I get `2010-04-05 18:51:18.885 TestString[6823:a0f] Helloxx` as output. There is no space left.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *newString = [myString substringToIndex:5];
```

That will ensure that there are only 5 characters in the string, but beware that this will also throw an exception if there are not *at least* 5 characters in the string to begin with. How are you handling this string? Is it being displayed to the user? Is it being written to a file? The code that you posted does not reproduce the error, so perhaps you should post the code that you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

the other way u can use.. by stringByReplacingCharactersInRange

```
token = [token stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withString:@"*"];
```

"token"is your want to replace the NSString and "i" is you want to change NSString by "*"